# Stata: Running sum with missing values

Tags: sum, stata

I would like to get the running sum over `j`, e.g. for row `_n` and `j=3` I would like to get `x[_n] + x[_n+1] + x[_n+2]`.

I thought to do the following trick:

```
    by grouping: gen foo = sum(log(x))
    by grouping: replace foo = foo - foo[_n - `y'] if _n > `y'
```

However, this is not robust to missing values. `sum()` generates `0` for a missing value, while I need the cumulative sums to be `.` if at least one of the values to be summed over is `.`. How would I achieve that?

I need it to be working for large `j` too, so manually adding these up is not feasible.

Comment: Say rather that `sum()` ignores missing values. Its result will be non-zero if the non-missing values have cumulative sum non-zero.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to interpret and work it out:

```
clear
set more off

input ///
id myvar
1 3 
1 4 
1 . 
1 8 
1 7
1 2
1 .
1 8
2 3 
2 4 
2 . 
2 8 
2 7
2 2
2 .
2 8
end

// this?
bysort id: gen s = cond(!missing(myvar), sum(myvar), .)

// or this? (or something else?)
clonevar s2 = s
bysort id: replace s2 = . if missing(s2[_n-1]) & _n > 1

list, sepby(id)
```

It's not clear to me if you want any of these.

Comment: This is helpful technique but it isn't what the OP wants, even also using  the technique of differencing the cumulative sum, as this ignores missing values only in the present observation. The condition in `cond()` could be extended, but not concisely for long windows.

Answer (score 0):

Stealing Roberto's reproducible example (given none such in the post) another way to do this is using `tsegen` (SSC), which must be installed with `ssc inst tsegen`. It is essential to `tsset` or `xtset` the dataset. `tsegen` has wired into the syntax a way of stipulating the minimum number of non-missing arguments, here all of them.

```
clear
set more off

input ///
id myvar
1 3 
1 4 
1 . 
1 8 
1 7
1 2
1 .
1 8
2 3 
2 4 
2 . 
2 8 
2 7
2 2
2 .
2 8
end

sort id, stable
by id: gen t = _n 
tsset id t 

tsegen run = rowtotal(F(0/2).myvar, 3) 

list , sepby(id) 

     +----------------------+
     | id   myvar   t   run |
     |----------------------|
  1. |  1       3   1     . |
  2. |  1       4   2     . |
  3. |  1       .   3     . |
  4. |  1       8   4    17 |
  5. |  1       7   5     . |
  6. |  1       2   6     . |
  7. |  1       .   7     . |
  8. |  1       8   8     . |
     |----------------------|
  9. |  2       3   1     . |
 10. |  2       4   2     . |
 11. |  2       .   3     . |
 12. |  2       8   4    17 |
 13. |  2       7   5     . |
 14. |  2       2   6     . |
 15. |  2       .   7     . |
 16. |  2       8   8     . |
     +----------------------+
```